Restore simulators
Space was tight on a 1/4Tb drive so I've rm -rf ~/Library/Developer
Upon installation of xcode 15.4 and running my app I now get
'/Users/agraph/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0563D8C6-6301-4B6D-B0E1-EEFED95EC8A2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/Frameworks/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC' (no such file), '/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21F79/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC' (no such file)

After
xcrun simctl delete all

and creating sim for the device/ios version pair I got the same error.
I think I have installed that 17.2 simulator by simctl after the grand removal but something is still missing.
UPD To think of it WebRTC might not be platform framework but somthing that's shipped with this app. I am confused : Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ seems like an immutable directory. What is app framework is doing there then?

One problem with removing that directory is that triggers a larger cleanup of command line  developer tools. If you manually reinstall the command line tools does that help xcrun perform?

$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: note: Command line tools are already installed. Use "Software Update" in System Settings or the softwareupdate command line interface to install updates

indeed git, etc are available. You are saying I'd better uninstall cmdline tools and reinstall?

Yes, Uninstalling both then reinstalling might be worth the time. Otherwise we have to dig into debugger and linker and figure why Xcode and such have hiccups.

I have removed /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools and have installed Xcode 15.2 in addition to 15.4 -> It does not affect the issue in any way. I'm not so sure now its even an Apple framework. I might have troubled you for nothing if it's part of the app I;m trying to get to run.

No trouble. Too bad it wasn’t an easy fix

Was not an Apple bug: WebRTC is not an Apple framework. At least not a public one -> the one in question was shipped with the project target of which was crashing on runtime.
